# Win batch: setting variable within nested  loop not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a long script that I have condensed to the following lines of code to illustrate the issue I am having. I have tried some suggestion by StackOverflow users to no avail, so hopefully your feedback will help me and future users. NOTE: this code works, except for setting the pdfREP nested variable.

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set pdfREP=false

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('dir /o /b \\path2document\*.rp?') do (
    findstr "," \\path2log\%%a > 1.log
    if not errorlevel 0 (
        :: do something
        )
    if errorlevel 0 (
        findstr /B /I "p" \\path2document\%%a > 1.log
        if errorlevel == 0 (
            set pdfREP=true
            echo RSP File: %%a >> 2.log 
        )
    )   
)
```

Basically the issue is that in \path2document I have multiple files, and within each I look for a comma. If no comma is found then I want to know if there is a particular letter inside the file's text. If the text is found, the I am setting a previously defined variable to TRUE, instead of FALSE. However, the "if errorlevel == 0" can be true if different syntax (%errorlevel%==0,%errorlevel% EQU 0), and it will NOT set the variable pdfREP to TRUE. If the issue is that the variable is not set until after the loop iteration, then how can I use this variable in the rest of my code? I would like to use this variable later on, so setting it is most important. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: I edited out the resolution since such should have been posted as an answer (of course according to [answer])…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows batch has an "interesting" way of handling nested variables.  [This article](http://www.computing.net/howtos/show/batch-script-variable-expansion-win200-and-up/248.html) might help.

Personally, when my batch files get this complex, I switch to a different language.  My first choice is generally Python, but if you'd like to stay inside the Microsoft ecosystem, then vbscript or PowerShell would work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is no longer valid; that's why the basic contents should have been summarised in the answer…

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the IF command and the errorlevel value.

IF command description indicate that you may directly use in the condition the ERRORLEVEL word followed by a number indicating a given errorlevel. This way, the following two IF commands are right:

```
if not errorlevel 0 (
    :: do something
    )
if errorlevel 0 (
```

However, the following command is bad written:

```
if errorlevel == 0 (
```

In this case, you must use !errorlevel! to indicate to take the current errorlevel value after executing the last line:

```
if !errorlevel! == 0 (
```

Independently of the above said, this is the way that I would do that:

```
if not errorlevel 0 (
    echo The errorlevel is less than zero 
) else if errorlevel 0 (
    echo The errorlevel is greater than zero
) else (
    echo The errorlevel is zero
)
```

Comment: Hi Acini, this code actually does work. As I mentioned, it worked to do %errorlevel%==0,%errorlevel% EQU 0, or errorlevel 0. However this is not my issue. The issue is setting the nested variable. User jdigital gave me a link that I looked at, but it is sort of badly worded, and much of what it said, I tried, so it didn't help much.

Comment: @Bc. To `set pdfREP=true` when previous `findstr ...` returns 0, just use `if !errorlevel! == 0 (` as I said before...